# Pass list element as function argument

Tags: python

I'm building an Instagram upload bot. Function `upload` is expected to receive an image location and then proceed to upload it. The issue I'm facing is that the loop that goes through each individual element on an image list prints back numbers, instead of a string.
I have isolated the code to:

```
print(col)
for i in col:
    print(i)
```

NB: In an ideal scenario the print(i) would be replaced by upload(i)

Output:

```
    ['C:\\Users\\aa\\Desktop\\Programming\\Instagram\\media\\pexels-eberhard-grossgasteiger-1612360.jpg', 'C:\\Users\\aa\\Desktop\\Programming\\Instagram\\media\\pexels-northwoods-murphy-1878810.jpg', 'C:\\Users\\aa\\Desktop\\Programming\\Instagram\\media\\pexels-stein-egil-liland-3510717.jpg']
[[[235 229 229]
  [235 229 229]
  [235 229 229]
  ...
  [239 233 235]
  [239 233 235]
  [239 233 235]]

 [[235 229 229]
  [235 229 229]
  [235 229 229]
  ...
  [239 233 235]
  [239 233 235]
  [239 233 235]]

 [[235 229 229]
  [235 229 229]
  [235 229 229]
  ...
  [239 233 235]
  [239 233 235]
  [239 233 235]]

 ...

 [[ 59  51  38]
  [ 60  52  39]
  [ 61  53  40]
  ...
  [159 144 137]
  [133 118 113]
  [115 100  95]]

 [[ 58  50  37]
  [ 58  50  37]
  [ 58  50  37]
  ...
  [143 128 121]
  [132 117 112]
  [100  85  80]]

 [[ 58  50  37]
  [ 58  50  37]
  [ 58  50  37]
  ...
  [119 104  97]
  [ 81  66  61]
  [ 80  65  60]]]
[[[23 19 18]
  [23 19 18]
  [22 18 17]
  ...
  [23 19 16]
  [23 19 18]
  [22 18 17]]

 [[23 19 18]
  [23 19 18]
  [22 18 17]
  ...
  [22 18 15]
  [22 18 17]
  [21 17 16]]

 [[23 19 18]
  [23 19 18]
  [22 18 17]
  ...
  [20 16 13]
  [21 17 16]
  [20 16 15]]

 ...

 [[23 18 15]
  [23 18 15]
  [23 18 15]
  ...
  [39 34 30]
  [39 34 30]
  [39 34 30]]

 [[23 18 15]
  [23 18 15]
  [23 18 15]
  ...
  [39 34 30]
  [39 34 30]
  [39 34 30]]

 [[23 18 15]
  [23 18 15]
  [23 18 15]
  ...
  [39 34 30]
  [39 34 30]
  [39 34 30]]]
[[[ 27  39  53]
  [ 27  39  53]
  [ 27  39  53]
  ...
  [ 27  36  53]
  [ 27  36  53]
  [ 27  36  53]]

 [[ 27  39  53]
  [ 27  39  53]
  [ 27  39  53]
  ...
  [ 26  35  52]
  [ 26  35  52]
  [ 26  35  52]]

 [[ 27  39  53]
  [ 27  39  53]
  [ 27  39  53]
  ...
  [ 26  35  52]
  [ 26  35  52]
  [ 26  35  52]]

 ...

 [[ 31  35  38]
  [ 36  40  43]
  [ 30  31  33]
  ...
  [ 77  88 106]
  [ 77  90 107]
  [ 77  90 106]]

 [[ 25  26  28]
  [ 34  34  36]
  [ 31  29  32]
  ...
  [ 76  87 107]
  [ 74  87 106]
  [ 74  87 104]]

 [[ 26  26  28]
  [ 34  34  36]
  [ 33  28  32]
  ...
  [ 77  88 110]
  [ 76  89 108]
  [ 75  88 107]]]
```

Here is the whole code:

```
from instabot import Bot 
from skimage.io import imread_collection
import random
import json
import os

imageDir = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\aa\\Desktop\\Programming\\Instagram\\media")

col_dir = 'C:\\Users\\aa\\Desktop\\Programming\\Instagram\\media\\*.jpg'
col = imread_collection(col_dir)

with open('C:\\Users\\aa\\Desktop\\Programming\\Instagram\\quotes.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
  

def getQuote():
    quote = random.choice(data)
    return ('"'+quote['text']+'" - '+quote['author'])
getQuote()
print(getQuote())
bot = Bot() 
bot.login(username = "",  password = "")

def upload(path):
    bot.upload_photo(path, caption=(getQuote()))
    for item in imageDir:
      if item.endswith(".REMOVE_ME"):
          os.remove(os.path.join("C:\\Users\\aa\\Desktop\\Programming\\Instagram\\media", item))
print(col)
for i in col:
    print(i)
```

I'm new to python so I am probably making some basic mistake, but I would appreciate if you could make the for loop print a normal string back as the str function had no effect

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the loop. each item in `col` is pixel data of an image(i.e r,g,b), how will having each pixel be the text of a pixel help?

Comment: I'm trying to get their location as a list, and pass this list of image locations to the function upload one by one

Comment: As you can see here: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html?highlight=imread_collection#imread-collection, imread_collection returns an ImageCollection object, this is not a list with addresses to  your images but an object that holds the actual images. and that's what's being printed, the actual images as a nested list of color values for every pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to get all the paths, but what you are doing is actually read the images and get the pixel data. To get all the paths you can use the `glob` module.
Add `from glob import glob` to your imports and change the following line:

```
col = imread_collection(col_dir)
```

to this:

```
col = glob(col_dir)
```